# Delete all logs under a heading in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to delete all instances of, i.e.,

```
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2018-01-24 Wed 16:55]--[2018-01-24 Wed 17:15] =>  0:20
:END:
```

under a header in org-mode? That is, to delete (under a header) all multi-line strings that begin with `:LOGBOOK` and end with `:END:`?

Comment: The (almost) general answer for all variants of that questions is [my answer on how to parse and modify an orgmode buffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38354/2370). In the first run you modify `org-element-map` such that it shows you the parsing tree in the second run you define your transformation rules. Maybe it is a bit more complicated than just automatically editing text but it is the wonder weapon in the sense that it gives correct and complete results. One exploits the strictly defined orgmode syntax and the high-quality parser built-in into orgmode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defun mw-org-log-delete ()
  "Delete logbook drawer of subtree."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (org-log-beginning))
    (when (save-excursion
            (save-match-data
              (beginning-of-line 0)
              (search-forward-regexp org-drawer-regexp)
              (goto-char (match-beginning 1))
              (looking-at "LOGBOOK")))
      (org-mark-element)
      (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
      (org-remove-empty-drawer-at (point)))))
```