# Clearing the Contents of an Org-Mode Header Programmatically?

Tags: org-mode

If we have

```
* Header 1
Some contents.
```

Is there a way to programmatically kill the contents of `Header 1` so that it remains like:

```
* Header 1
```

?

Answer (score 8):

There isn't a command for deleting the subtree (i.e., the head line and all its contents), but there is a command to `mark` it. We can use that to get what you want:

```el
(defun clear-subtree ()
  (interactive)
  (org-mark-subtree) ;; mark the current subtree
  (forward-line) ;; move point forward, so the headline isn't in the region
  (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)) ;; delete the rest
)
```

Comment: Maybe, you could mention that `org-mark-subtree` puts point at the start of the current subtree (i.e., on the headline) and mark at the end.

Comment: And that `org-mark-subtree` is by default binded to `C-c @`, which is very useful.

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways of removing the contents of a headline. Taylor gave you already a [straight-forward text editing method](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38352/2370) which is good and which you should perhaps accept as an answer.

But there is more. Orgmode has a [well defined syntax](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html) and also routines for parsing and printing.

So one way to change the contents of your org buffer is:

- parsing the org buffer via `org-element-parse-buffer`
- search the parse tree for the element you want to change via `org-element-map`
- modify the element in the parse data
- print out the parse data via `org-element-interpret-data`

I give you an example for your special case of removing the content of `Header 1`. The following code returns a string with the text of buffer `test.org` modified with the contents of `Header 1` removed.

```el
(with-current-buffer "test.org"
  (let* ((data (org-element-parse-buffer)))
    (org-element-map data 'headline
      (lambda (el)
    (when (equal
           (car-safe (org-element-property :title el))
           "Header 1")
      (setf (nthcdr 2 el) nil) ;; Here we remove the contents from this headline.
      )))
    (org-element-interpret-data data)))
```

Which method you should use strongly depends on the actual use-case.

Comment: You define the local variable `mylist`, but you don't actually use it anywhere?

Comment: @Tyler Thanks for the hint. `mylist` was for debugging only. It was a walking dead;-).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can use `org-map-entries` to do this as well:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results none
(let ((MATCH t)
      (SCOPE nil)
      (SKIP nil)
      (spacing nil))

  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
     (let ((name (nth 4 (org-heading-components))))
       (if (string= name "Header 1")
           (save-restriction
             (org-mark-subtree)
             (forward-line)
             (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
             ))
       )) MATCH SCOPE SKIP))
#+END_SRC

* Header 1
Content of header 1 
* Header 2
Content of header 2
```

If you run the source code block with `C-c C-c`, it will remove `Content of header 1` under `Header 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to find the bounds of what you want to clear, and then move to the `END` and keep deleting the previous character until the value of point is smaller than the value of `START`. You may also want to preserve metadata information by setting the optional argument to a non-nil value.

```
(defun clear-subtree (&optional metadata)
  (let (start)
    (save-excursion
      (org-back-to-heading t)
      (if metadata
          (org-end-of-meta-data nil)
        (forward-line 1))
      (setq start (point))
      (org-end-of-subtree t)
      (while (>= (point) start)
        (delete-char -1)))))
```